# Getting an error when i click on edit customer in the admin panel

Tags: customer, edit

Here is the log for the error

```
   a:5:{i:0;s:123:"Source model "customeractivation/resource_attribute_source_customeractivation" not found for attribute "customer_activated"";i:1;s:3149:"#0 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "c...')
#1 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php(75): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array)
#3 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tabs.php(58): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account->initForm()
#4 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#7 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#9 /home/allholde/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#10 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/allholde/...')
#11 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#12 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#17 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php(151): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#18 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->editAction()
#19 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#20 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /home/allholde/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /home/allholde/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /home/allholde/public_html/index.php(130): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}";s:3:"url";s:79:"/index.php/admin123/customer/edit/id/2388/key/989271bfd789f6f13c18fb5c9969f707/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok im still not sure the cause or maybe it was an uninstall of an extension but this is how i solved it

deleted the following from table `eav_attribute`

```
customeractivation/resource_attribute_source_Customerpayment
customeractivation/resource_attribute_source_Iswebsitelive
customeractivation/resource_attribute_source_StoreType
```

Answer (score 1):

In your system,there have an `eav attribute` which `Source model` does not exits in your db.which source model is `customeractivation/resource_attribute_source_customeractivation`.

**This model class file does not exits in system.**
This class may be

```
MOduleNameSpace_MOduleName_Model_Resource_Attribute_Source_Customeractivation
```

This may be `dropdown` and `multi select attribute` .You need to create this attribute from `eav_attribute`.

Please see about [source model](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-custom-attribute-source-type/) at here

Answer (score 1):

install any customer attribute extension then go admin panel->customer->manage attribute delete attribute code "customer_activated"

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having a similar issue as reported here.

https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation/issues/74